# Oracle TNS error with Ruby on Rails Rake command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, rake, tns

I am trying to use the Ruby on Rails Rake command to migrate to an Oracle database. My `database.yml` file contains the following:

```
development:
    adapter: oracle
    database: album_development
    sid: orc1          
    username: system
    password: root
```

On my PC I have set `ORACLE_SID=orcl.`

When I run Rake,migrate, I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
The driver encountered an error: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

Can you tell me if I need to modify my `listener.ora` file to get this to work? My `listener.ora` file is as follows:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Lenovo-PC)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

The output of the lsnrctl Status command is as follows:

```
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                21-APR-2016 11:14:15
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 7 min. 43 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\Lenovo-PC\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=Lenovo-PC)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=Lenovo-PC)(PORT=8080))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "xe" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Can anyone help / make a suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried connecting to xe rather than orcl e.g sid: xe

Comment: Yes, I have tried with sid: xe It doesn't work either

Comment: typo orc1 \ orcl  ???

Comment: Neither orc1 or orcl work

Answer (score 0):

firstly you can check the database is accessible by using the `TNSPING` command

e.g: `TNSPING xe`

could it be you have used a one rather than an L sid: orc1  should be sid: orcl perhaps ?

Comment: Kevin, 
Thanks for your reply. I ran the command, and the results are as follows; TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 21-APR-2016 13:04:16

Copyright (c) 1997, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Lenovo-PC)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE)))
OK (10 msec)

Comment: if you change database.yml to point to xe rather than orcl do it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Kevin,

Thanks for your help. I changed my `database.yml` to:

```
development:

  adapter: oracle
  database: xe
  username: system
  password: root
```

This allowed me to connect to the database. I now have another problem, but I think I can tackle that one. Kind regards, Sean